Logic App AuthorizationFailure - vnet integration needed
Im trying to make my environment little bit more secure. I have added the Private endpoint for my Storage account.
But now the isse is that my logic app cant reach and fails
"body": {
    "message": "AuthorizationFailure\r\nclientRequestId: 7772864e-9a15-41ca-b02f-xxxxx",
    "status": 403,
    "error": {
        "message": "AuthorizationFailure"
    },
    "source": "azureblob-we.azconn-we-003.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

Logic is something new to me so I would appreciate your input on how to add the Vnet integration to already exisitng logic app.
The sources I found in google I think they are little bit over dates cause my UI is slightly different as I dont see anywhere "networking" tab under settings in the left side panel.


Which plan are you using?


I dont see anywhere "networking" tab under settings in the left side panel.

Yes, you will not have Networking for Consumption plan. If you want to use Vnet Integration, you will have to use Standard Plan for Logic app.

Logic is something new to me so I would appreciate your input on how to add the Vnet integration to already exisitng logic app.

Firstly, create Logic app with Standard Plan and then in Settings, click on Networking:

Then in Storage account create/add a vnet:

Then in Logic app Networking, click on Not Configured as below:

Then Integrate vnet :

Then vnet gets integrated:

Note: Make sure both Logic app and Storage account and vnet are in Same Location.
So, you have to migrate or create a new logic app with standard plan to use Networking with it.
Also for information on Vnet integration refer SO-Thread.

thanks for the info,  and in my situation, how can I make my consumption plan to connect to private storage account?

No, you cannot connect as there is no networking section in consumption plan. only way i see is to use standard plan

I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584407/azure-logic-app-consumption-access-to-storage-account-behind-vnet

That was old. currently as of today, this is not supported in consumption plan

how can that be possible? So i have to migrate my logic app to standrad logic app?

Yes, if you can migrate well and good or else, create a logic app with standard plan or workflow service plan, in that you will have networking.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
